# Retrieve a value from a set where the key comes from another set in Open Policy Agent (OPA)

Tags: opa, open-policy-agent

I've read through the OPA 'Policy Language' page, but my problem is only sorta addressed...looking for clarity here ;)

I have two sets:

```
"servers": {
  "server1": [ "silver" ],
  "server2": [ "gold" ]
}

"plan": {
  "gold": [ "1000" ],
  "silver": [ "100" ]
}
```

in my data section.  I need a rule that given `input.server = "server2"` will return `"1000"` ...so a set lookup that provides the key for a second lookup.

I was trying this:

```
rate msg = {
  p := servers[input.server]
  msg := plan[p]
}
```

but OPA barfs all over that.  It looks do-able to me, but not having any success in coming up with the rule for this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`servers[input.server]` is going to return a list (`[ "1000" ]`) and not `"1000"`, so you'd need to get the item out of the list if you want to use it as the key to look up in the `plan` object. Additionally, the `rate` rule had some syntax wrong. This should work:

```
servers := {
    "server1": ["silver"],
    "server2": ["gold"]
}

plan := {
    "gold": ["1000"],
    "silver": ["100"]
}

rate = msg {
    p := servers[input.server][0]
    msg := plan[p]
}
```

Finally, and not meant as nitpicking :), but there aren't any *sets* in your data -  only lists and maps. Use curly brackets, i.e. `{ "1000" }` instead of `[ ]` if you want those.

Comment: This gives me an error ``"code": "rego_unsafe_var_error",  "message": "var servers is unsafe"`` ... I am loading in servers via a json file, so I'm guessing that has something to do with it?

Comment: Yes, then you'll need to reference them as `data.servers`, etc.. see https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/SyX9w46rd1

Comment: Aha!  That's what I was missing.  Works now!  Thank You!